Can someone help me with stripe google pay integration?
Can someone help me with stripe google pay integration? I am using express checkout element but when I am trying to mount that element I am getting  errors like
"unable to download payment manifest ""https://www.google.com/pay"
I have followed stripe doc and added the below code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Google Pay Integration</title>
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
</head>

    <div id="express-checkout-element">
    <!-- Express Checkout Element will be inserted here -->
    </div>
    <div id="error-message">
    <!-- Display error message to your customers here -->
    </div>

    <script>
        const stripe = Stripe('pk_test_.....................');
        const options = {
        mode: 'payment',
        amount: 1099,
        currency: 'usd',
        appearance: {/*...*/},
        };
        const elements = stripe.elements(options);
        const expressCheckoutElement = elements.create('expressCheckout');
        expressCheckoutElement.mount('#express-checkout-element');
    </script>
</body>
</html>``


To start, can you confirm that you're set up for Google Pay? Go here: https://docs.stripe.com/elements/express-checkout-element and confirm that in the rendered Express Checkout Element, you see the Google Pay button on your browser. We have to verify that your browser does support Google Pay first.

@hmunoz No, I can't see the button. Though Google pay is active on my account and I have added my domain also.

Do you have a card added to your Google Pay wallet?

@hmunoz No. Is it something that I need to do from my stripe account?

You do that on your Google account/wallet. Having a valid card registered on your Google Pay wallet is what makes the Google Pay button show up on Express Checkout Button
